# Convert .bmp file into.tiff format

Tags: geotiff-tiff, convert, bigtiff

Can I convert one big .bmp file (size is 19GB (high resolution city map)) into  one or several .tiff format files without dividing this .bmp file into smaller tiles?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where did you get stuck? Without any further information, the answer would most probably be: 'Yes, you can'.

Comment: did you try `gdal_transform`?

Comment: I need free software or maybe some site that can transform big .bmp files into .tiff(or BigTiff) format. I've tried trial version of GlobalMapper, some sites. Nothing work for 19gb file. I haven't tried "gdal_transform" thx i will try